# DNS zone file not working

Tags: dns, bind

I have been stuck on this one for a while.
I have to make it so that there is an CNAME for www to the srvAmparo.walter.sil. Also that has the IP of 192.168.1.1 and lastly the SOA and NS entries have to made such that I can do lookups on my client to [www.walter.sil](http://www.walter.sil).
No matter what I do, I cannot seem to fix this issue as it will not recognize walter.sil or [www.walter.sil](http://www.walter.sil).

My zone file:

```
$ORIGIN walter.sil.
$TTL 3H
@               IN      SOA     @       srvAmparo.walter.sil. (
                                        20211006;
                                        1D ;
                                        1H ;
                                        1W ;
                                        3H );
@               IN      NS      srvAmparo.walter.sil.
srvAmparo       IN      A       192.168.1.1
www             IN      CNAME   srvAmparo
```

And my named.conf file:

```
zone "walter.sil" IN {
        type master;
        file "walter.sil";
        allow-update { none; };
};
```

This is the error message using nslookup on my client.
(192.168.1.1 is the dns server I'm setting up)
Also the DNS has a forwarders option set, so anything else gets resolved.
[image: error printout of nslookup: SERVFAIL]

Comment: What are the permissions on your zone file?  The symptoms you're describing can happen if the `named` (aka BIND) process can't read the zonefile.  You'll also need to ensure that the (empty) path you've supplied to the zonefile is correct.  Try `named-checkconf -l | grep walter` and make sure you see the output line: `walter.sil IN _default master`.  If you don't, odds are good that BIND isn't seeing your zonefile for one reason or another.

Comment: Hi Jim, and thanks for answering on such short notice!! I've looked into the permissions and it is exaclty as you said. user and group perms should be "named". Now it finally works. I never seemed to have found this hint or notice until some Indian on YouTube casually typed it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!
The command: chown named.named walter.sil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jim, I was able to pinpoint the issue.
I had no idea that permissions for that file have to be of user and group "named".
So changing the file perms: `chown named.named walter.sil`solved the issue. Everything else was set-up properly.